# How to create a backup schema script including System Tables in Sql Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup

I need to back up my entire DB including one table that's allocated in "Tables -> System Tables". When I try to generate the sql scripts to back up my DB this table isn't mapped in this scripts. Do I need to do something more to map this table to the scripts?

Comment: What table of yours is in system tables, why is it there, and how did it get there? Also why don't you backup your database to backup your database, instead of scripting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating scripts of objects usually isn't the best backup method.

There shouldn't be any actual tables listed under Tables > System Tables.  Those should all be catalog views unless you've hacked the system objects to put one of yours tables in there.

Comment: Entity framework migrationHistory tables are located in system tables.

Comment: Those wouldn't be use objects so they shouldn't be included in his script, which I assume is going into source control.